# Optional include for INCS , LIBS and OBJS in GNUMakefile , make version 3.82

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am using make version GNU Make 3.82. I compile my code using command `make MYFLAG=1` . I have an application which can use either of two different versions of a library. Variable `MYFLAG` indicates which application and corresponding files should be compiled for creating the binary. Thus, based on the value of `MYFLAG`, I need to include some more paths in variables `INCS`, `LIBS`, and `OBJs`. So after common files were added to these variables, I was trying to conditionally add appropriate additional paths according to this form:

```
ifeq(,$(findstring MYFLAG, $(CXXFLAGS)))
    INCS += -I/home/my_folder/ \
endif
```

Note that `CXXFLAGS` is updated if it sees that variable `MYFLAG` has value equal to 1 and appended with the value `-DMYFLAG` in it.

But `make` version 3.82 rejects my makefile with error `missing endif` giving me GNUMakefile name and pointing me to last line of the makefile.  What's wrong with my makefile, and how should I fix it?

Edit: There was some typo here while posting the question as MadScientist pointed it out. Main Issue was when adding new includes in INCS variable i finished the last include with "" which had therefore treated endif as part of the INCS flag, causing a missing endif error.

I think we can close this issue as this is now fixed. Thanks to everyone for pointing different suggestions in comment.

Comment: Please format your question such that it becomes understandable.

Comment: Also please use _cut and paste_ of your actual code.  Please don't try to retype it by hand.  Doing so introduces subtle errors.  For example above you are missing an open paren between the `$` and `findstring` in `$findstring MYFLAG...`  Is that really missing or did you just mistype it here?

Comment: As MadScientist mentioned, you're missing the `(` in `$(findstring`, which looks to be your issue.   Note that looking for `MYFLAGS` will match `-DMYFLAGS` _and_ `-DNOTMYFLAGS`, _and_ `-DFLAGSNOTSET=MYFLAGS`...  It might be better if you moved your test to check the value of `$(MYFLAGS)` rather than using `$(findstring ...)`  on `CXXFLAGS`   (or use `$(filter -DMYFLAGS=%,$(CXXFLAGS))` instead...)

Comment: You also have to have a space after `ifeq` and before the opening paren.  However, this **CANNOT** be the actual makefile you're using, if you get the error `missing endif`, because the makefile you've provided will report `missing separator` on line 1.  So, whatever your makefile actually says, it's certainly not what you've shown us here and there's no way we can help you.

Comment: @MadScientist : yes there was a typo while writing the if condition on SO actual issue was last include also had `\` before endif resulting into that error.